# What to do with unanswered questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, help-center

What to do if your question doesn't get answered and you don't have enough reputation to safely place a bounty?

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: Er... "*safely* place a bounty"? What is unsafe about bounties?

Comment: [How can I draw attention to someone else's unanswered question below the bounty rep level?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94513) would be more exact, @Servy.

Comment: @Louis, i meant without losing privileges because of lack of reputation.

Comment: Re-evaluate your question. Perhaps it is unclear? Are tags too general or too specialized? Adding more detail also moves it back up again -- for whatever that is worth something.